# cypress check div not clickable

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-origin

The piece of code below shows as a checkbox and I'm trying to use cypress to click it but it isn't working even though I selected it.

```html
<button class="p-button p-component p-disabled primary-button p-button-raised font-semibold" 
 type="button" disabled="" id="search-button" 
 aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="search-menu" 
 data-v-17vc126c="">...</button>
```

Here's what my cypress code looks like:

```
When('User clicks checkbox, disable form', () => {
 cy.get('.p-button.p-component[aria-controls="search-menu"]').click();
});
```

**Here's the error I get:**

> Timed out retrying after 15050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is disabled:
>
> ```html
> <button class="p-button p-component p-disabled primary-button p-button-raised font-semibold" type="button" disabled="" id="search-button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="search-menu" data-v-17vc126c="">...</button>
> ```
>
> Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
>
> The command was expected to run against origin https://myDevSite.com but the application is at origin http://localhost:8080.

This commonly happens when you have either not navigated to the expected origin or have navigated away unexpectedly

Crazy thing is I used this exact code on another element and it worked with no errors.
Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The element has a disabled attribute which will prevent a interactions with it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Answer (score 2):

The obvious step you can take is shown in the message

```js
cy.get('.p-button.p-component[aria-controls="search-menu"]').click({force:true})
```

but the user won't click when button is disabled (natch), so you must find out how to enable it from the web page and do that instead.

Comment: I tried that as well before I posted and it didn't work.  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Why do you want to click disabled checkbox? What result do you expect? I mean if you want to verify that it's disabled you should better compare 'disabled' parameter's value when checkbox is disabled and enabled and make assertion that it's really disabled now.

Comment: Why not click a disabled checkbox? It's rather simplistic to assume everything has to be about a user action.